# How to execute a function before waiting with setInterval in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, frontend

When using setInterval(f, time), is it possible that the function f is executed first before waiting for a time?

Answer (score 2):

Not within the setInterval function itself. Just call it explicitly.

```
 f();
 setInterval(f, time);
```

Answer (score 0):

Note : Even if you set an interval. It is not assured that the function will be triggered on time because javascript is single threaded and it will wait until the current executing function in the stack finishes.

The function passed inside setInterval wont fire the first time inside the setInteral. we have to invoke the function manually.

func();

setInterval(func, time);

Answer (score 0):

If You want the function to be triggered before waiting x time, and then execute again after said time, and again and again, you have to explicitly call the function f before starting the interval like so:

```js
var f = function () {
    document.write('<p>Function executed</p>');
  }

f();

setInterval(f, 3000);
```

Mind that the time is in milliseconds, so if you want the function to repeat every 1 seconds you should use the number 1000.

If you want the interval to be more precise consider putting it in a web worker, however support is not available in all browsers.